# Different sites give different answers for this series sum

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

For the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{((2n+1)^2-4)^2}$ wolframalpha gives answer $\displaystyle\frac{\pi^2}{64}$, but another site gives $\displaystyle\frac{\pi^2}{64}-\frac{1}{12}$: http://www.emathhelp.net/calculators/calculus-2/series-calculator/?f=1%2F%28%282n%2B1%29%5E2-4%29%5E2&var=&a=0&b=inf.

What is the correct answer?

Comment: You are summing  a sequence of non-negative numbers, the first term $\frac19$ is already bigger then $\frac{\pi^2}{64} - \frac{1}{12}$. So the second answer is definitely wrong. I'm doing the sum by hand, I get same answer as WA.

Comment: Out of curiosity @achille hui, "doing it by hand" are you just manually summing terms until they become too small to affect the overall sum? Or how does one calculate it by hand?

Comment: @plsmakemedomath By hand, I mean transform the series to a sum between $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}$ and another telescoping series.

Comment: sums of this type are regulary calculated here on MSE. Just sniff araound a bir...

Comment: You can use the fact that $\zeta(2) = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
S&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{((2n+1)^2-4)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(4n^2+4n-3)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{((2n-1)(2n+3))^2}\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2n+3-(2n-1)}{((2n-1)(2n+3))^2}=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2(2n+3)}-\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n-1)(2n+3)^2}\\
&=\frac{1}{16}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}-\frac{2}{16}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n-1)(2n+3)}+\frac{1}{16}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n+3)^2}
\end{align}$$
Using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402451/evaluating-a-summation-of-inverse-squares-over-odd-indices) we see
$$\begin{align}
&\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}=\frac{3}{4}\zeta(2)+1\\
&\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n+3)^2}=\frac{3}{4}\zeta(2)-1
\end{align}$$
And we can use telescoping on the middle-term as follows
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n-1)(2n+3)}&=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n-1)}-\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n+3)}\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n-1)}-\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n-1)}\\
&=\frac{1}{4}(-1+1)=0
\end{align}$$
[And so](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-limits-k-1-infty-frac1k2?noredirect=1&lq=1)
$$S=\frac{1}{16}\times\frac{3}{2}\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{64}$$