# Sum of a sequence of reciprocals of square of odd natural numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

If $$a_{n}=\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{5^2}+\frac{1}{7^2}+....+\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}$$where $n\in N$.

Then prove that

$a_{n}<\frac{1}{4}$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402451/evaluating-a-summation-of-inverse-squares-over-odd-indices

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_Reciprocals_of_Squares_of_Odd_Integers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The $n$th term is less than $\frac{1}{4n(n+1)}$. This replaces your series with a standard series that sums to $\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: Welcome to math SE. If you know latex then write the equations as you do in latex.

Comment: Thanks Math Lover. I really must learn how to write equations in something other than Word.

Comment: I've edited the mathematical expressions for you. I hope you'll figure out how to write math expressions/equations in mathjax or latex.

Comment: Thanks again - I'll refrain from answering until I have learnt.

Comment: It shouldn't discourage you posting your answers. Writing mathematical expressions in latex/mathjax is very easy. You can easily learn that. Here is a tutorial https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 10):

$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}<\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{2n(2n+2)}\stackrel{\text{telescopic!}}{=}\frac{1}{4}. $$
Since the LHS equals $\frac{\pi^2}{8}-1$ by Fourier series, this turns out to be a proof of $\pi^2<10$.

Comment: Well done! (+1)

Answer (score 6):

Here's a sketch of a direct proof that only requires calculus.  Note that for each $k$,  we have $$\frac{1}{(2k + 1)^2} \leq \int_{k-1}^k \frac{1}{(2x + 1)^2}\,dx.$$

This implies that each $a_n$ is less than $$\frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{25} + \frac{1}{49} + \int_{3}^\infty \frac{1}{(2x + 1)^2}.$$

Calculating this integral directly gives the upper bound of $$\frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{25} + \frac{1}{49} + \frac{1}{14} \approx .242 < \frac{1}{4}.$$

This method is a good technique for computing an upper bound on a sum (or a corresponding lower bound by altering the integral).

Comment: Clear and concise.  (+1)

Comment: @MarkViola: it is possible to be even more concise!

Answer (score 0):

adding and subtracting $1 + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{4^2} + \ldots + \frac{1}{(2n)^2}$, and using Basel problem we get
$\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n = \sum_{k=1}^{2n+1} \frac{1}{k^2} - \frac{1}{4}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k^2}\right) - 1 = \frac{\pi^2}{6} - \frac{1}{4}\frac{\pi^2}{6} - 1 = \frac{\pi^2}{8} - 1$